# clang plugin ASTConsumer

Tags: plugins, llvm, clang

Hey I tried to generate call graph of the given .c or .cpp file. I write a clang plugin to generate call graph. I wrote following function.

```
class CGASTActionConsumer:public ASTConsumer{
  CallGraph *CG;
    public:
        CGASTActionConsumer(CallGraph *inCG):CG(inCG){}
      virtual bool HandleTopLevelDecl(DeclGroupDef DG)
       {
         for(DeclGroupRef::iterator i=begin(),e=end();i!=e;++i)
          {
            if(FunctionDecl *FD = dyn_cast<FunctionDecl>(D))
              {
                if(/* check function is valid for insertion to graph   */)
                  CG->addToCallGraph(FD,FD->isGlobal()); // add node in call graph
              }
          }
       }

};
```

when i try to print the graph from the outside HandleTopLevelDecl function then it will not print any thing. but when I call from print function from HandleTopLevelDecl function it will print the output for each node. Can anyone tell me why this happen?
thnks.

Comment: Where exactly do you put print statements in your code snippet?